# How to disable input language key combination in one particular program?

Tags: windows, hotkeys, input-languages

I am using CTRL+SHIFT key combination for changing input language. Problem i have is that in one application i use this key combination is part of several other combinations and too often i switch language by accident.

Is there a way to disable language switching or key combination CTRL+SHIFT for one application?

Please, don't suggest changing my input lang key combination - i tried it and because i have been using CTRL+SHIFT for over fifteen years i just couldn't get used to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an autohotkey script.

```
#IfWinActive, "Notepad"
CTRL & SHIFT::return
```

Just replace Notepad with your application title.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, it lead me to a correct working script. Perhaps they have changed something, but the correct string to use now is #IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad.

Comment: Oops.  I thought it would accept the title bar text as well as ahk_class . . .

Comment: Actually this completely removes support for CTRL+SHIFT from the application however i need it for key combinations like CTRL+SHIFT+LEFT / RIGH